# When i set "config.option.file_or_dir" in the "conftest.py" file, value is not been used

Tags: python, pytest

When I set the parameter **"config.option.file_or_dir"** in the **"conftest.py"** file, the value set is not been used. It runs all the tests.
When I read the parameter **"config.option.file_or_dir"** it's display my value i had set.

### conftest.py

```
def pytest_configure(config):

    if len(config.option.file_or_dir) == 0 and ini_paser.get('TestRun', 'value') is not "":
        config.option.file_or_dir.append(ini_paser.get('TestRun', 'value'))
        print("file_or_dir - after =" + str(config.option.file_or_dir))
```

### test.ini

```
   [Suites]
   value=Smoke

   [Browser]
   env_title=Browser
   value=chrome

   [DPR_ENV]
   env_title=DRP Environment
   value=SQA

   [Customer]
   env_title=Customer
   value=mstqa

   [User]
   env_title=User
   value=mstqa_d_admin,mstqa_c_admin

   [TestRun]
   value=Software_Update/
```

### command line

```
xxx/scr/proj/DRP/tests/pytest --ini test.ini
```

I do not put any parameter in the command line. I will set which to tests to be executed from the ini file via the section **"TestRun"**.

Comment: You mean "not being used"?  What exactly does "config.option.file_or_dir" return?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! There seems to be quite a lot of code in your example that is irrelevant for your specific problem, which makes it harder to pinpoint the exact problem. Try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @BillM. The "config.option.file_or_dir returns a list that contains filename or directories. Yes you are correct not being used.